# Alternate use of View.INVISIBLE in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In xml we use `View.INVISIBLE` to just don't show the view at all, but it still takes up space for layout purposes. What is the alternative in jetpack compose?

```
AnimatedVisibility(
    // true or false
) {
    Button() // button code.
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can build a custom modifier to measure the Composable to take up space.

Something like:

```
fun Modifier.visible(visible: Boolean) = if (visible) this else this.then(Invisible)

private object Invisible : LayoutModifier {

    override fun MeasureScope.measure(
        measurable: Measurable,
        constraints: Constraints
    ): MeasureResult {
        val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
        return layout(placeable.width, placeable.height) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: very nice and clean solution..

Comment: This seems to work to a limited extent. If visible transitions from visible to hidden, it behaves as expected.  But transitions from hidden to visible don't result in the items being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I just use the `alpha` Modifier extension function to achieve this functionality which may cover 90% of the use cases, unless you're using the alpha channel for other purposes. I do it like this, for example, on a text:

```kotlin
Text( modifier = Modifier.alpha(0f), text = "Lorem Ipsum")
```

Comment: Using alpha like this will cause a graphics layer to be created but nothing drawn into it. If it's a single composable, that probably won't matter much, but it could be a performance consideration for scrolling content.

Comment: Ok do this Text(), but if item was clickable, then the invisible item could still be clicked -- not like View.INVISIBLE that OP asked for.

Comment: @Mike, not sure what you mean exactly but clickability can also be disabled via modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

The Accepted answer is perfect , but you can also look into the below code.

```
@Composable
fun ShowContentOrNot() {

    var isShow by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        if (isShow)
            Text(text = "Some content")

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Button(onClick = {
            isShow = !isShow
        }) {
            Text(text = "Hide/Show")
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: But this removes `Text` from composition, right, and no longer takes up space for layout purposes?

Comment: No it will remove the space as well !